# input value on php form between pages

Tags: php, html, css

I need you help. I have a form, and 2 inputs inside.
I have also those php code.
The idea is change css elements, by 2 colors the user insert, when my url is "URL?MyColors=true",
The function MyColors(), will run.
And then, the css apply by the inputs values.
I also want when client is submit, the url with get Get parameter "Mycolors=true",
so that why the submit button is with the next "formaction":
"".
It's work as well, but only for current page, and "URL2?MyColors=true".
When I'm refreshing the page, the 2 colors not apply anymore.
I don't know what the reason.
Who can help me?

```
<form action="" method="post" id="myform">
  myColor1: <input name="myColor1" type="text" />
  myColor2: <input name="myColor2" type="text" />
<input formaction="index.php?MyColors=true" type="submit" name="submit">
<button class="refresh" onclick="refreshPage()">Refresh</button>
</form>

 

<?php
if(isset($_GET['MyColors'])){
 MyColors();
}

function MyColors() {
  $_SESSION["myColors"] = "&MyColors=true";
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $myColor1 = $_POST['myColor1'];
        $myColor2 = $_POST['myColor2'];
    }
     else {
    $myColor1 = $_SESSION['myColor1'];
    $myColor2 = $_SESSION['myColor2'];
    }

    $_SESSION['myColor1'] =  $_POST['myColor1'];
    $_SESSION['myColor2'] =  $_POST['myColor2']; 

    echo "<style>.bgimg-1{background: {$myColor1}!important;}
    .last{color:{$myColor1}!important;-webkit-text-stroke-color:{$myColor2}!important;}
    .first{color:{$myColor2}!important;-webkit-text-stroke-color:{$myColor1}!important;}
    .addToCart{background:{$myColor1}!important;color:{$myColor2}!important;}
    .addToCart i, a.addToCart a ,  a.addToCart span {color:{$myColor2}!important;}
    .moreInfo{color: {$myColor1}!important;background: {$myColor2}!important;}
    a.moreInfo i{color: {$myColor1}!important;}
    button[type='button'].view_data {color: {$myColor1}!important;background: {$myColor2}!important;}
    p.rotate {color: {$myColor1}!important; }
    body {background: {$myColor2}!important;}
    .categoriesTitle {color: {$myColor1}!important;}
    .overlay {background: {$myColor1}!important;}
    a.liAfter {color: {$myColor2}!important;}
    .categoryTitles {color: {$myColor2}!important;background: {$myColor1}!important;}
    .catWrapperImageCatPage::after {background: {$myColor2}!important;}
     p.cat_title {color: {$myColor1}!important; }
    </style>"; 
   }
?>
```

Comment: What does `refreshPage()` do?

Comment: <?php
function refreshPage() 
{
header("refresh: 3;");
}
?>

Comment: You can't run a PHP function on the client. So are we talking about a manual refresh here?

Answer (score 0):

your code should be...

```
<form action="index.php?MyColors=true" method="post" id="myform">
    <label for="mycol1">myColor1:</label>
    <input name="myColor1" id="mycol1" type="text">
    <label for="mycol2">myColor2:</label>
    <input name="myColor2" id="mycol2" type="text">
    <input type="submit" name="col-submit" value="Submit_Color">
    <button class="refresh" onclick="refreshPage()">Refresh</button>
</form>


<?php
if(isset($_POST["col-submit"])){

  session_start();

----------
bla bla...
----------

?>
```